# MySQL and PHP - insert NULL rather than empty string

Tags: php, mysql, null, sql-insert

I have a MySQL statement that inserts some variables into the database. I recently added 2 fields which are optional ($intLat, $intLng).  Right now, if these values are not entered I pass along an empty string as a value.  How do I pass an explicit NULL value to MySQL (if empty)?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO data (notes, id, filesUploaded, lat, lng, intLat, intLng)
          VALUES ('$notes', '$id', TRIM('$imageUploaded'), '$lat', '$long', 
                  '$intLat', '$intLng')";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO data (notes, id, filesUploaded, lat, lng, intLat, intLng)
          VALUES ('$notes', '$id', TRIM('$imageUploaded'), '$lat', '$long', NULLIF('$intLat',''), NULLIF('$intLng',''))";

Answer (score 169, accepted):

To pass a NULL to MySQL, you do just that.

```
INSERT INTO table (field,field2) VALUES (NULL,3)
```

So, in your code, check `if $intLat, $intLng` are `empty`, if they are, use `NULL` instead of `'$intLat'` or `'$intLng'`.

```
$intLat = !empty($intLat) ? "'$intLat'" : "NULL";
$intLng = !empty($intLng) ? "'$intLng'" : "NULL";

$query = "INSERT INTO data (notes, id, filesUploaded, lat, lng, intLat, intLng)
          VALUES ('$notes', '$id', TRIM('$imageUploaded'), '$lat', '$long', 
                  $intLat, $intLng)";
```

Comment: This doesn't add a mysql NULL value. This set the attribute to the string "NULL" which is different from the mysql NULL value. I'm just saying that you wrote two different things, first is correct the second not so much I think.

Comment: @G4bri3l: In the `$query` string, `$intLat` and `$intLng` are not quoted.  So, when the variables are interpolated, it will be `, NULL, NULL);`.

Comment: Oh yeah I see that now. Nice! Thanks for taking the time to point it out to me ;)

Comment: @G4bri3l: No prob.  I'm here to help :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat
What about if I have a code like this `$sql="INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ($field1, '$field2', '$field3', '$field4', '$field5', '$field6')"`?

`$field3` and `'$field5'` might be empty strings.

Comment: @alessadro: This question is very old.  If you are concatenating variables into a SQL query like that, then you are doing it wrong!  Please switch to using prepared statements in either PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: empty() check will also consider 0 input as empty. This can be wrong for integers (e.g., minimum storage temperature = 0 and it is valid).
if($value == ""){$value = NULL;} is better.
Also, $value = "NULL" is not good either - it will replace empty string values with "NULL" text.

Comment: @bbe: While I agree that `empty()` may not be the best here, `$value == ''` doesn't fix the issue.  `if(0 == '')` evaluates to `TRUE`, so that won't help here.  Also, I am *not* setting the values to `"NULL"` text.  I'm building the SQL query (`$query`), so that it will insert a `NULL` value into the database.

Comment: this answer isn't accurate , adding NULL into the query becomes empty in MYSQL

Comment: How did this answer get so many upvotes... You can't insert the string "NULL" to make it null. Then it's not really null, it has a value which is the string "NULL."

Adding empty quotes won't insert null either. It will insert an empty string.
And using the keyword ```null``` in php will also insert an empty string.

To insert NULL in a row, you simply don't insert anything, like this:

```INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ();``` and make sure you have that column set to nullable in sql.

Comment: @AMR if you leave it empty, PHP throws the following error: "Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '' for column"

Answer (score 29):

This works just fine for me:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('', NULLIF('$date',''))
```

(first `''` increments id field)

Comment: NULLIF takes 2 parameters `NULLIF(expr1, expr2)` .  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif

Comment: I think this is better because you can do in just one line

Comment: Not so simple with prepared statements.

Comment: the only one valid answer for pdo, at least for me.

Answer (score 18):

If you don't pass values, you'll get nulls for defaults.

But you can just pass the word NULL without quotes.

Comment: He'll only get NULL for default, if the table is set up that way.

Comment: To me that's what "optional" means.

Answer (score 13):

All you have to do is: `$variable =NULL;` // and pass it in the insert query. This will store the value as NULL in mysql db

Comment: No need for quotes around the "NULL".

Answer (score 5):

Normally, you add regular values to mySQL, from PHP  like this:

```
function addValues($val1, $val2) {
    db_open(); // just some code ot open the DB 
    $query = "INSERT INTO uradmonitor (db_value1, db_value2) VALUES ('$val1', '$val2')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    db_close(); // just some code to close the DB
}
```

When your values are empty/null ($val1=="" or $val1==NULL), and you want NULL to be added to SQL and not 0 or empty string, to the following:

```
function addValues($val1, $val2) {
    db_open(); // just some code ot open the DB 
    $query = "INSERT INTO uradmonitor (db_value1, db_value2) VALUES (".
        (($val1=='')?"NULL":("'".$val1."'")) . ", ".
        (($val2=='')?"NULL":("'".$val2."'")) . 
        ")";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    db_close(); // just some code to close the DB
}
```

Note that null must be added as "NULL" and not as "'NULL'" . The non-null values must be added as "'".$val1."'", etc.

Hope this helps, I just had to use this for some hardware data loggers, some of them collecting temperature and radiation, others only radiation. For those without the temperature sensor I needed NULL and not 0, for obvious reasons ( 0 is an accepted temperature value also).

Comment: For column defined integers, the other solution it works fine, but for text fields, I had to break up the query as above into a string concatenation, like radhoo did above.   $query = "INSERT INTO uradmonitor (db_value1, db_value2) VALUES (". "NULL". ", ".$val2.")";

Answer (score 2):

your query can go as follows:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO data (notes, id, filesUploaded, lat, lng, intLat, intLng)
      VALUES ('$notes', '$id', TRIM('$imageUploaded'), '$lat', '$lng', '" . ($lat == '')?NULL:$lat . "', '" . ($long == '')?NULL:$long . "')";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: $intLat, and $intLng are the optional ones.

Comment: This will not work. There are quite a few things wrong with this code snippet (apart from using the wrong variables, as Rocket pointed out). Because of the precedence of the ternary operator, you'll need parentheses around the expression. But crucially, you are still surrounding the column value in single quotes, so you are back to square one, assigning a string, not a database `NULL`. Also, you are using PHPs `NULL` (unquoted) keyword, which evaluates to an empty string in a string context, so again, you are assigning an _empty string_.

Answer (score 2):

> For some reason, radhoo's solution wouldn't work for me. When I used the following expression:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO uradmonitor (db_value1, db_value2) VALUES (".
    (($val1=='')?"NULL":("'".$val1."'")) . ", ".
    (($val2=='')?"NULL":("'".$val2."'")) . 
    ")";
```

> 'null' (with quotes) was inserted instead of null without quotes, making it a string instead of an integer. So I finally tried:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO uradmonitor (db_value1, db_value2) VALUES (".
    (($val1=='')? :("'".$val1."'")) . ", ".
    (($val2=='')? :("'".$val2."'")) . 
    ")";
```

> The blank resulted in the correct null (unquoted) being inserted into the query.

Answer (score 1):

Check the variables before building the query, if they are empty, change them to the string NULL

Answer (score 1):

you can do it for example with

```
UPDATE `table` SET `date`='', `newdate`=NULL WHERE id='$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

**2022 | PHP 7.3 | MySQL 5.7**

Accepted answer by Rocket Hazmat gives me "NULL" as a string. So I change it to:

```
$intLat = !empty($intLat) ? "'$intLat'" : NULL;
$intLng = !empty($intLng) ? "'$intLng'" : NULL;
```