# Function to Make Empty String NULL for MySQL Insertion in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is similar question to [MySQL and PHP - insert NULL rather than empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620391/mysql-and-php-insert-null-rather-than-empty-string) but I'm still encountering the problem.

I'm trying to create a function so that an empty string is inserted as a NULL into MySQL.

I create the function IsEmptyString:

```
function IsEmptyString($val){
    if (trim($val) === ''){$val = "NULL";}
}
```

Before inserting the the variable, I escape it and then I call the function above. I've also tried `$val = NULL;`

What am I doing wrong? Also should I call the function before escaping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return $val at the end of the function:

```
function IsEmptyString($val){
    if (trim($val) === ''){$val = "NULL";}
    return $val;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but have the same problem. Can I just call the function, e.g. `IsEmptyString($name)` or do I have to set  `$name = IsEmptyString($name)`.

Comment: You need to call $name = IsEmptyString($name).  Another option is to define the function as:  function IsEmptyString(&$val) then you do not need to return the value

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning the value. This should work

```
function IsEmptyString($val){
    if (trim($val) === ''){$val = "NULL";}
return $val;
}
```

Also you're assigning your variable to a string and not `null`.

This line `$val = "NULL";`

should be

```
$val = null;
```

Also see PHP's `isset()` and `empty()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can return the result with `return`...

```
function IsEmptyString($val)
{
  if (trim($val) === '')
    return 'NULL';
  else
    return $val;
}
```

...or you have to pass the variable as reference (note the & before the $val)

```
function IsEmptyString(&$val)
{
  if (trim($val) === '')
    $val = 'NULL';
}
```

Comment: @Rufinus - It seems that the OP is using the string 'NULL' to build an SQL statement. The function is a modification of the given example, it has other flaws too, as a misleading name for example.

Answer (score 0):

alternativly, you can pass val as reference.

```
function IsEmptyString(&$val){
    if (trim($val) === ''){$val = "NULL";}
}
```

however, be carefull not to send "'".$val."'" to the database;

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good candidate for a ternary operator:

```
function valOrNull($val) {
    return (trim($val) === '') ? NULL : $val;
}
```