# Update with blank field entry, MySql shows it as zero

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have this `<input type="text" name="Fax" id="faxbox" maxlength="9" value="<?php echo $row['Fax'] ?>" />`

I want to leave it blank on submit. On Data Base, that column (as int) is set to allow nulls too.

But when i submit, my empty/blank field is turn to 0 (zero) by MySql. I want that appear NULL instead 0.

What should I do? I try `if(empty($_POST['Fax'])){$Fax=NULL;}` but wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to insert `NULL` value in MySQL using php, you need to do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (field,field2) VALUES (NULL,3)
```

in your case, try this:

```
$Fax = !empty($Fax) ? "'$Fax'" : "NULL"; 
INSERT INTO tableName (Fax) VALUES ($Fax);
```

**[more on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4620409/491243)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually use a string null, e.g.

```
$Fax = 'NULL';
```

A php null will be converted into an empty string if you use it in a string context anywhere.

---

followup:

if you have:

```
$Fax = null;
$sql = "INSERT INTO .... VALUES ($Fax)";
```

you end up with

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ()
```

because the PHP null was converted to an empty string. But if you have

```
$Fax = 'null'; // a string whose contents is the word 'null'
```

then the query statement will actually be

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES (null)
```

because the value of the string was the word null, which then will be treated as an sql null.

Comment: My Fax column on DBase is set as INT. Im sorry if i wasnt clear, but what I want, is to save a few data from a form in DB and one of that entrys is empty, but mysql save it as 0. I need that Mysql save it as NULL