# Inserting form input into database and when empty doesnt insert as NULL

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form and everything works well. However when I escape the input using mysqli real_escape_string, if the input was left blank by the user, it enters blank in the database and not as NULL. here is the code I have for the variable.

```
    $website = '"'.$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['website']).'"';
```

The variables that are not escaped , ie a variable that is numeric and has only 7 chars appears NULL if nothing is input by the user.

Not sure what to do and Google has not been helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4620409/2611927

Comment: Thanks for some reason could not find that. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the value like:

```
$website = "NULL";

if (isset($_POST['website']))
  $website = "'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['website']) . "'";
```

.. insert to db

Comment: with the quotes? wont that just make the variable equal to a string "null"