# Insert into SQL if PHP values blank (NULL)

Tags: php, sql

Greets everyone,

I have a PHP form with 40 fields to fill in when a job is completed by a driver.  Not all these fields will be filled in.  My problem with the new mariaDB update is, the INSERT INTO execution fails on the blanks.

I have set all the SQL default to NULL, but if the page tries to set a "" blank, the SQL doesn't make it a NULL.

Is there anyway way, other than a conditional blank check on every field, to bypass then blanks?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL and PHP - insert NULL rather than empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620391/mysql-and-php-insert-null-rather-than-empty-string)

Answer (score 0):

try this for your values

```
$a = isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : null;
```

if you are using php7.0+ then you may use Null Coalescing Operator
[refer](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

Comment: Or just `$_GET['a'] ?: null`.

Comment: Actually `$_GET['a'] ?? null`.