# Make a value into NULL instead of empty in php

Tags: php, null

I can't make the empty value to be checked as *NULL* in database instead of leaving an empty space when I am inserting a value.

I don't want to leave an empty/blank space for an entry when it has no value.
So if there is no file selected, make that entry into *NULL*

Is it unnecessary to be in *NULL*?

```
if (empty($_FILES['logo']['name'])) {
  $code = NULL;
  } else {
}
```

Comment: How do you update/insert this value, and is the column nullable?

Comment: @Qirel The column is NULLable, yes

Comment: Why not change the if statement to `if (!empty($_FILES['logo']['name']))` and then run the inserts within that code block?

Comment: check mark default NULL in phpmyadmin

Comment: You must set the NULL value explicit in mysql. INSERT INTO <TABLE> (<COL>) VALUES (NULL)

Comment: @DevsiOdedra It is set as default

Comment: Add the code. Sounds like you are using `$code` in the insert..

Comment: Please update your question, the problem is not your if/else, it is in the sql syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a normal problem with null-able strings. For a quick solution, you can change your code to:

```
$code = NULL;
if( !empty($_FILES['logo']['name']) ){
 ...
}
```

For more details, you can check this question:
[MySQL and PHP - insert NULL rather than empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620391/mysql-and-php-insert-null-rather-than-empty-string)

Answer (score 0):

$logo = (!empty($_FILES['logo']['name']) ? "logo" : "NULL");
try this